# Optional type is assigned at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am following a tutorial for springBoot framework. The netbeans shows error for the below code. Error is `incompatible type:Optional<UsersDTO> cannot be converted to UserDTO`

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<UsersDTO>getUserById(@PathVariable("id") final Long id){
    UsersDTO user = userJpaRepository.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<UsersDTO>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You want to know what is `Optional`? Or why java checks types in assignment statement?

Answer (score 2):

JPA Repository findById returns Optional, as the item may not be found.

Therefore this code doesn't compile because the return type is wrong and doesn't match findById

You need to have the right type, which is Optional like so:

```
 Optional<UsersDTO> user = userJpaRepository.findById(id);
```

Once you have this item you can check user.isPresent() and user.get() to obtain the UsersDTO object if it is present.